# SQL Server : update and insert in one query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some trouble trying to create an update/insert query.

From a `.CSV`, I create a temporary table (heading and one datarow as a example):

| sku | product_id | description_en | description_ru | description_lv |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EE1010 | 4633 | Description in Eng | Description in Rus | Description in Lat |

I intend to iterate over each row and update/insert rows into another table with this query:

```
UPDATE ProductLocalized
SET FullDescription = (CASE 
                          WHEN LanguageID = 7 THEN description_en
                          WHEN LanguageID = 12 THEN description_ru
                          WHEN LanguageID = 14 THEN description_lv
                       END)
WHERE LanguageID IN (7, 12, 14) 
  AND ProductID = product_id;
```

My problem is how to add the `INSERT` part if some of the languages missing?

Comment: Hint:  `MERGE` does this.

Comment: You can't `INSERT` and `UPDATE` in the same statement, apart from with a `MERGE`. If you don't want to use a `MERGE` then you would use an "upsert", which is an `UPDATE` statement followed by an `INSERT` statement (a search will show you how to write these).

Comment: for use merge see this link https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1704/using-merge-in-sql-server-to-insert-update-and-delete-at-the-same-time/

Comment: I strongly suggest you normalize this table into `ProductDescription` with columns `ProductID, LanguageID, Description`. Then you can do a normal joined `merge`

Comment: Are you attempting to update or insert multiple rows in the target from each single row in your source? I.e., you need to add/update the russian row, the english row, and the lat(vian) rows that match product ID?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Upsert in SQL to achieve this. Please find below quick example for the same.

```
create table dbo.test_source
(
id int identity(1,1),
language varchar(50),
description varchar(100)
)
create table dbo.test_dest
(
id int identity(1,1),
language varchar(50),
description varchar(100)
) 

Insert into dbo.test_source  values ('English', 'British language')
Insert into dbo.test_source values ('Hindi', 'Indian language')
Insert into dbo.test_source values ('Chinese', 'China')
Insert into dbo.test_dest  values ('English', 'British language')
Insert into dbo.test_dest values ('Hindi', 'NA') 

SELECT * FROM dbo.test_Source
SELECT * FROM dbo.test_Dest

Result
id          language                                           description
----------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           English                                            British language
2           Hindi                                              Indian language
3           Chinese                                            China



id          language                                           description
----------- ------------------ -------------
1           English                                            British language
2           Hindi                                              NA


MERGE  dbo.test_dest  as MyTarget
USING  
(
    SELECT 
    ID,
    Language,
    Description
    FROM  dbo.test_source
) as MySource
ON MyTarget.Language = MySource.Language 
WHEN MATCHED AND NOT 
    (
        MySource.Description = ISNULL(MyTarget.Description, '')    
    )
THEN  
    UPDATE 
    Set MyTarget.Description = MySource.Description      
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
THEN  
    INSERT (Language, description)
    VALUES (MySource.Language
    ,MySource.Description);


SELECT * FROM dbo.test_Dest


Result


id          language                                           description
----------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           English                                            British language
2           Hindi                                              Indian language
3           Chinese                                            China
```

We can see record with 2 got updated with source table description and record with id 3 got inserted as it was not exist into destination table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IF EXIST or IF NOT EXIST statements to filter the records and then apply the INSERT or UPDATE Commands.

Example:

IF NOT EXIST ( Condition ) { INSERT }

IF EXIST ( Condition ) { UPDATE }

An alternate way is:

IF EXIST( Condition )

```
 update
```

ELSE

```
 insert
```